# How can I convert the number of letters of an editText into a variable?

Tags: java, string, android-edittext

I would like to find out the number of current entries. This also works as long as it is not deleted. If something is deleted, the length does not change. The Part which is already written should be highlighted. What can I do?

```
public class TypeSpeed extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView tvactivetext;
    private EditText etTextInput;

    private TextWatcher text = null;
    int randomnumber;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_type_speed);
        randomnumber= (short) (Math.random() * (2 - 0 + 1) + 0);

        final String[] texte = {"Dies ist der erste Text und die Schwierigkeit ist meist nicht die Geschwindigkeit sondern die Anfälligkeit für ", "Dies ist der zweite Text", "Dies ist der dritte Text", "Dies ist der vierte Text"};
        SpannableString str;
        str = new SpannableString(texte[randomnumber]);

        tvactivetext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvactivetext);
        etTextInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextInputText);

        tvactivetext.setText(str);

        text = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                int length = etTextInput.length();
                str.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, length, 0);
                tvactivetext.setText(str);


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            }
        };

        etTextInput.addTextChangedListener(text);


    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Somehow the CharAt does not work. Error message: "Cannot find symbol method charAT(int)"

Comment: Add the whole method to the question

Comment: Also, clarify exactly what happens with your current codes and what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: I have edited my post. Could you check it out again? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int length = etTextInput.getText().toString().length();
```

Comment: This works most of the time. But when I press delete it does not affect.

Comment: what happen at delete?

Comment: Nothing. It not change the amount of highlighted characters.